# react-native-dropdown-picker listed items not showing properly (Overlay)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

I have created DropDown picker with the "react-native-dropdown-picker" package all items are listed but it looks transparent on another component. anyone can help me to fix this issue?

[image]

Here My Source code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

  
const App = () => {
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
    {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'}
  ]);

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
        <DropDownPicker
          open={open}
          value={value}
          items={items}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setValue}
          setItems={setItems}
        />
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
        <Button title="Check"/>
        <Text>Hello world</Text>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
export default App;
```

Expected:
Listed items need to show properly without overlay, the buttons want to appear after the dropdown with scrollview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be transparency alone. If you notice, the raised buttons are appearing above the lines of the dropdown.

That means `z-index` is also an issue here.

Add a `dropDownContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white',zIndex: 1000, elevation: 1000 }}` to your `DropDownPicker` component.

This should fix `transparency` as well as the `zIndex`.

Comment: Added style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 10000 }} to DropDownPicker but no luck. still same issue coming.

Comment: Try creating a reproducible using https://snack.expo.io/. I created this one - https://snack.expo.io/@nisanth-reddy/groaning-macaroni-and-cheese - and it seems like it is working fine.

Comment: In web view its working fine but in android not working. Can you switch to Android and run once see the diffrence. https://snack.expo.io/@elavarasan-r/groaning-macaroni-and-cheese

Comment: Updated my answer. Assuming you are using the latest version of the package, check this https://snack.expo.io/@nisanth-reddy/groaning-macaroni-and-cheese

Comment: Found solution from your example code. I have added "elevation: 1000" at dropDownContainerStyle its working fine. The exact code "dropDownContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white',zIndex: 1000, elevation: 1000}}". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

For me the accepted answer does not work in ios. To fix ios issue i had to set the parent's view zIndex, however this lead to problems in android. Here is how your code should look like.

```
<View style={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? {zIndex: 100} : {}}>
     <DropDownPicker {...dropDownProps} />
</View>
```

I'd recommend to use the above as a starting point, make sure it all works fine in this plain version and start adding up more things to the style

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Here is the solution to this overlap problem please try this way it 99.9% works!!!
============
  <View style={{zIndex: 2000}}> // this work because of this
    <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Tags</Text>
    <DropDownPicker
      style={{
        width: dynamicSize(340),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginVertical: dynamicSize(10),
        borderColor: colors.GRAY_E0,
      }}
      dropDownContainerStyle={{
        width: dynamicSize(340),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderColor: colors.GRAY_E0,
      }}
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
      // theme="DARK"
      multiple={true}
      mode="BADGE"
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this library, I take care not to use the ***containerStyle*** property to avoid such situations

Answer (score -1):

It is Easy to solve:

```
<DropDownPicker
  zIndex={3000}
  zIndexInverse={1000}
  ...
/>
<DropDownPicker
  zIndex={2000}
  zIndexInverse={2000}
  ...
/>
<DropDownPicker
  zIndex={1000}
  zIndexInverse={3000}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, i had set height for the parent element. removing the height worked

**With Height**

[image]

**Without Height**

[image]