# React native react-native-dropdown-picker dropdown list opacity issue

Tags: react-native, overlay, react-native-dropdown-picker

I'm new to React Native, how can I modify my code to change the opacity of the dropDown list so that the text 'My text' become hidden?

[image: Example]

Here my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      label: 'Option 1',
      value: 'option1',
    },
    {
      label: 'Option 2',
      value: 'option2',
    },
    {
      label: 'Option 3',
      value: 'option3',
    },
  ]);

  return (

      <View style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 15
        }}>
      <Text>Selected Value: {value}</Text>
        <DropDownPicker
          open={open}
          value={value}
          items={items}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setValue}
          setItems={setItems}
          placeholder="Select an option"
          containerStyle={{ width: 400, backgroundColor: "white"}}
          listItemLabelStyle={{ fontSize: 16 }}
          showArrowIcon={true}
          hideSelectedItemIcon={true}
          theme="LIGHT"
        />

        <Text>My text</Text>

      </View>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I'have tried with adding the option

```
listParentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor:  'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'}}
```

but without effect.
I've tried to follow the instructions in here but without effect: [react-native-dropdown-picker listed items not showing properly (Overlay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558933/react-native-dropdown-picker-listed-items-not-showing-properly-overlay).

Comment: I find it hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do here. The Dropdown has nothing to do with your 'My text' element. Maybe you want 'My text' to be transparent when you select one of the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the code. You need to manage the opacity of the `Text`:

```
{open ? <Text style={{ opacity: 0 }}>My text</Text> : <Text>My text</Text>}
```

or you can also hide the overall `Text` by:

```
{!open && <Text>My text</Text>}
```

Here is the preview:
https://snack.expo.dev/HqW6LKFbN

Comment: Let me know if still face any issues & contribute to others by upvoting & accept answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but I discovered the react-native-element-dropdown dropdown component, and I prefer to move in this component well suited to my case (here the link with the documentation of this component https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-element-dropdown#dropdown-example)

Comment: That's good, keep it up